# AWS cognito - Can we modify the redirect URL supplied by Amazon Cognito when it authenticates using google provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

[AWS cognito doc says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html) Developers must add Amazon Cognito User Pool domain URL https://your-user-pool-domain/oauth2/idpresponse in the Google app's Authorized redirect URIs. 
Is it possible to modify the redirect url provided by cognito when signing -in with google so that call back directly come to application instead of aws-cognito.

For example: I can add a valid redirect url as "https://myapp/callback/" in google app. When signing-in with google using aws cognito hosted page - aws coginto supply the redirect url as "https://myapp/callback/" instead of https://your-user-pool-domain/oauth2/idpresponse

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use the Amazon Cognito User Pool domain URL. That's the only supported method if you are using Cognito. Otherwise Cognito wouldn't know anything about your external identity.

Comment: cognito federated authentication flow (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) clearly says app should handle the login with external provider and post login app should send access_token/id_token to cognito ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/authentication-in-the-browser-with-amazon-cognito-and-public-identity-providers/  - read step 4). To enable this flow,  the callback must come to application so that app can send id_token(for google) and access_token( for facebook) to cognito. shouldn't this flow be uniform across all platform?